# Vector, Hashtable. В чем минус синхронизированности?

Tags: java, коллекции, concurrency

Vector, HashTable, Stack являются устаревшими коллекциями, и пишут что их не используют в виду синхронизированности их методов. В чем минус синхронизации? Если однопоточная среда, это как-то влияет на их работу? Потокобезопасность это же хорошо. Если они устаревшие, зачем создавали синхронизированные коллекции в concurrent пакете? 
Извините за тупой вопрос, очень интересно просто. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Потокобезопасность это же хорошо.

Потокобезопасность не бесплатна, точнее очень не бесплатна, именно поэтому есть потокобезопасные и не потокобезопасные коллекции.

> Если однопоточная среда, это как-то влияет на их работу?

Такие коллекции работают значительно медленее, чем не синхронизированные аналоги

> Если они устаревшие, зачем создавали синхронизированные коллекции в
>   concurrent пакете?

Новые синхронизированные коллекции используют более быстрый алгоритм, когда блокируется не вся коллекция целиком при каждом чихе, а только часть (блок), поэтому Vector, HashTable, Stack не стоит использовать ни в многопоточности (они работают медленнее, чем новые коллекции), ни в однопоточном - они просто избыточны.

Если интересно более подробно разобраться с коллекциями советую посмотреть [мою статью](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/256877/)

**P.S.** В принципе, если вам производительность не важна, то ничего страшного не случится если вы будите использовать Vector, HashTable и т.п. вместо ArrayList, HashMap и т.д., они будут работать нормально. Но их использование считается плохим кодом и признаком плохого знания языка.